# table row in android xml layout

Tags: android

I have to set height between for two table row...any suggestion...i not get correct output

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/card1" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cardshadow" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: what is your expecting output? To set space between two table row put android:layout_margin="" in table row.

Comment: Do you want two tablerows, each one taking up a certain percentage of the device's height? Or do you just want to add a margin between rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableRow
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginDown="5dp" //could be any number
     android:id="@+id/tablerow1">

</TableRow>
<TableRow
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"// could be any number
     android:id="@+id/tablerow2">

</TableRow>
```

Note: they should be in a layout like tableLayout or something..
this code

```
android:layout_margin="2dp"
```

sets  space around the view layout, so layout margin top or down sets space around top and down.. when you use margin just like down it sets space in all rectangular aspects so yh..
let me know if it helps